# Как освободить порт если он занят

Tags: c++

У меня есть программа она занимает порт 4001 если ее не отключать и запустить еще одну программу она будет выдавать ошибку пока порт не закроется.
Вопрос, как освободить порт и при запуски программы захватить порт 4001.

Comment: Предусмотреть в программе завершение работы после получения какой либо определенной информации из сети через этот самый порт. Новая программа стартует, видит, что порт занят, подключается к нему (т.е. устанавливает соединение с первой программой) и передает той кодовую последовательность, по которой первая завершается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Грохнуть процесс, который слушает порт.

Comment: А как, заставить программу грохнуть другую программу?
Так наверно нельзя, антивирус будет ругаться.

Comment: Я бы оставил это действие администратору компьютера. Выдавайте осмысленный текст ошибки и завершайтесь.

Comment: Ошибки не приемлемы, мне нужно как то обойти ошибку.
Может есть способ проверить порт что бы запустить другой?

Comment: Вот вмешаться в другую программу и отобрать у неё порт - неприемлемо. Она такой подставы точно не ожидает. Проверить, что порт занят можно. Собственно нужно попытаться забиндить, и если не вышло посмотреть причину. Там для "порт занят" есть отдельный код ошибки. А дальше нужно или пожаловаться пользователю, или выбрать другой порт.

Comment: Так при открытии порта ловите исключение, если поймали, то пробуйте другой порт.

Comment: @cassius А какой код отвечает за поимки исключений портов?

Comment: Посмотрите пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126940/c-server-sockets-bind-error , а именно обработку ошибки вызова функции bind.

Comment: @cassius эта инструкция для другого языка

Comment: zip, вам для какого надо?

Comment: @cassius для C++